# Using Java to match a excel cell value to a text file

Tags: java, excel

So I'v looked around and can't really find anyone that is trying to do this so thought I would ask myself. What I am trying to do is take a Excel File look at a specific cell take it's value, run through a tab delimited text file (It should find a match) and then write the following column in the text file to another cell in the spreadsheet. Here is an example :

Cell A1 = LastName
Text File:

FirstName   John
LastName    Doe
MiddleName  Allen

It finds the match with LastName. Then looks at the next column in the text file for a value("Doe") and then writes that value to lets say Cell B1 in excel.

I feel like it would be fairly easy to do I'm just not sure how to make it take the "Doe" value from the text file when it matches the first column. I have to do this for about 3,600 cells hence why I'm trying to write a java program to do it.

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Read cell value from excel
- Check with the words in the text file
- If the text matches write the value in the next cell

Read the cell value use Apache Poi library.

```
InputStream book1= new FileInputStream("book1.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(book1); 

XSSFSheet sheet1 = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0)       // first sheet
Row row     = sheet1.getRow(0);        // first row
Cell cell   = row.getCell(0);
String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

to read words you can use Scanner.

```
Scanner words= new Scanner(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));

while (words.hasNext())
{
    String fileWord= words.next();
    if (fileWord.equals(cellValue )) // check if the Cell value equals the word in text file
    {
        // do your code.. write data to desired cell. use setCellValue() method.

    }
}
```

you need to iterate over your rows in the excel file to read the data from cells and then match it with the words in the text file. So,

Comment: Awesome Vembutech thanks for the help !